# Color Grid: figure out which box was clicked

Tags: java, android, teechart

My question concerns the Color Grid teechart.  I'm trying to write code so that when the user touches a box on the grid, only that box color will change.  I find the using chart.getHeight() and chart.getWidth() give the whole area of the chart and not just the color grid dimensions.  So right now, I'm estimating the length and width of the grid in pixels to estimate the box that the user touched.  Is there any way that I can figure out the exact amount of pixels of just the color grid length and height?  Additionally, I noticed a "clicked" method in the Color Grid api.  Is there anything already built-in that would allow me to find which box the user touched/clicked?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a simple example that uses the seriesClicked event. However, it seems to give a correct index but the cell colored seems to be in the opposite row:

```
    oldIndex = -1;
    tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);
    tChart1.getLegend().setVisible(false);

    ColorGrid col1 = new ColorGrid(tChart1.getChart());
    col1.setColorEach(true);
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
        for (int z=0; z<10; z++)
            col1.add(x, 1, z, Color.random());

    col1.addSeriesMouseListener(new SeriesMouseAdapter() {      
        @Override
        public void seriesClicked(SeriesMouseEvent e) {
            ColorGrid myGrid = (ColorGrid)tChart1.getSeries(0);
            int valueIndex = myGrid.clicked(e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y);
            if (valueIndex > -1) { 
                if (oldIndex > -1) {
                    myGrid.getColors().setColor(oldIndex, oldColor);
                }
                oldIndex = valueIndex;
                oldColor = myGrid.getValueColor(valueIndex);
                myGrid.getColors().setColor(valueIndex, Color.red);
                tChart1.getHeader().setText(String.valueOf(valueIndex));
                tChart1.getSeries(0).repaint();
            }
        }
});
```

I'll add to the defect list the need to revise the clicked function for the ColorGrid (TJ71016603)

In the meanwhile, a workaround could be to modify the given valueIndex as follows:

```
if (valueIndex > -1) {
    valueIndex = valueIndex / myGrid.getNumZValues() * myGrid.getNumZValues() + (myGrid.getNumZValues()-1 - (valueIndex % myGrid.getNumZValues()));
    if (oldIndex > -1) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Also, in case this helps anyone, I used calcXPosValue(double arg) and calcYPosValue(double arg) to calculate the exact length of the axes